# What does charge vs time represents?

Tags: electric-current, charge

[image: charge and current plots]

What does really curve of q(t) represents

We know current is defined as rate of change of change and in this q(t) curve current is first +ve and then -ve. But - ve current means flow of charge in opposite direction and if we look in the q(t) curve how could it represent the direction of motion of charge if it's just showing the charge passing through a cross section at an instance
And secondly what does q(t) having -ve values means does q(t) axis also represents polarity of charge.

My main question is how should i define this curve q(t) so that it matches with the definition of current.

Answer (score 0):

It's the gradient (slope) of the q(t) curve that gives the current.

So when the q(t) line segments have positive slope, going up, the current is positive (i.e. in a specific direction defined to be positive).

When the q(t) line segments have negative slope, going down, the current is negative (i.e. it's in the opposite direction).

Comment: As per your definition when slope of q(t) is - ve the current is also - ve. But - ve current means flow of charge in opposite direction, so if we take the interval from time 1-1.5 the slope is - ve but the motion of charge i.e q(t) is still in the same direction as for +ve current so how could we say current in - ve here